# Move cursor programmatically forward or back (easily) in Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Whenever I insert an image in my document with the following code,

```
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  var image = cursor.insertInlineImage(resp.getBlob());
```

the cursor is positioned *before* the image. It seems that it makes more sense to have the cursor be *after* what was inserted, as if it had been pasted.

I found [`Document.newPosition`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#newPosition(Element,Integer)) to achieve this, but it seems very complicated to use.

Here's what I gathered:

- get the current cursor
- get the element it is contained in
- parse its type (e.g., paragraph), and handle the logic with newPosition based on numbers of children, in case the cursor's at the end of the paragraph, etc.

I started trying to do this, but figured I'm doing something wrong because it's so complicated. Isn't there a simple function to move the cursor forward or back some number of elements, like with the arrow keys?

---

Edit: I found a simple solution for the image insertion. There's always an image *after* the cursor, so this works:

```
  var position = doc.newPosition(cursor.getElement(), cursor.getOffset()+1);
  doc.setCursor(position);
```

However, if moving the cursor arbitrarily forward, one must consider cases where `cursor.getOffset()+1` exceeds the `ContainerElement`.

Answer (score 5):

For images:

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
var image = cursor.insertInlineImage(resp.getBlob());
var position = doc.newPosition(image, 1); // image was just inserted, you want to go one cursor position past that.
doc.setCursor(position);
```

For text:

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
var sometext = cursor.insertText("Hokey Pokey");
var position = doc.newPosition(sometext, 11); // Move 11 characters into new text.   You can't move past the end of the text you just inserted.
doc.setCursor(position);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't define the variable doc, which makes it hard to appreciate.

Comment: var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();